# How to Embed Mapbox in iOS WidgetKit

Tags: cocoapods, mapbox, widgetkit

I have been attempting to embed a mapbox view into an iOS widget using WidgetKit but am hung up on the following error:

> Application extensions and any libraries they link to must be built with the `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY` build setting set to YES.

We are using CocoaPods for package management, and we have been using Mapbox in our main application for some time.

As far as I can tell, this is referring to the Mapbox POD and I don't believe I have the ability to modify that build setting. Can someone help set me straight here?

Answer (score 0):

While you can't embed https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios in a Widget, you can use https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxStatic.swift to fetch Maps image and display it in a Widget.